# Passing Key Commands in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm a total noob at this so please forgive me if my question is silly.

I have a script I use to remotely install .exe file on my network. The script has work fine without any issues until now. The updated version of the .exe now has a dialog box with "Next" that has to be clicked for the install to start.

My script looks something like this:

```
        $computers = get-content "Filepath"

        foreach ($c in $Computers) {

   try { 
       if (test -path "\\$c\C$\") {
       invoke-command - computername $c -scriptblock {cmd /c 
       "Filepath.exe -s"} Erroraction Stop -verbose - 
       InDisconnectedSession -SessionName $c 
       $job = receive-pssession -computername $c -Name $c 

       }
     catch {throw
     }
       }
```

My current .exe file that i'd like remote install no longer installs as the window now has a new "Next" button that has to be clicked to start the donwload/install process.

I am stumped.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could previously run the installer silently by passing `-s` on the commandline, but now it shows up a dialog despite `-s`?

Comment: If they don’t offer command line options to install then there’s not much you can do.

Comment: Sorta. So previously, there were no install/agree buttons on the .exe installer. Soon as you execute the .exe, it would download and install the rest of the components. 

The newly updated version of the same .exe now has a "Next" button that has to be clicked on the first window before it starts the download/install.

Comment: There are UI Automation tools you can use for this, or you can use SendKeys (ugly, can have timing issues), but doable.

Comment: UI automation API is built into Windows and it is possible to call it from PowerShell. There are basically two versions, UIA2 (.NET API) and UIA3 (native API), it depends on the target application which one works better.

Comment: For starters, you can use the Live Inspect tool from [Accessibilites Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/windows/overview/) to test if the installer actually supports UI automation. If Live Inspect lists the installer window including the "Next" button, then you can look for the _InvokePattern_ on the button. Try to execute the _Invoke_ method from the pattern. If that works from Live Inspect, you can do the same using script.